# How to configure multiple login pages for Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, session-timeout

Based on discussion at http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/10335161 there is a way to configure URL to redirect user in case of expired session:

auth.login.url=/url/to/login

what if I need different URLs based on URL I want to access? E.g. I have /test/login1, /test/login2, /test/login2 pages with login forms.

- If session expires and user tries to access page with URL /page/room1
  he should be redirected to /test/login1
- If session expires and user tries to access page with URL /page/room2
  he should be redirected to /test/login2
- If session expires and user tries to access page with URL /page/room2
  he should be redirected to /test/login2

and so on..

is there a way to do this using Liferay? I am pretty sure that such feature may require hook to be developed so the real question is how to get original URL user wanted to access once session has expired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get lastpath by

`LastPath lastPath = (LastPath)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.LAST_PATH);`

and from this, you can get information about last accessed url.

And by writing custom login post action using hook, you can redirect user to particular page based on lastpath.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for rapid and useful response. Seems to be working fine.